# how to move elements in hover with transform?

Tags: html, css, hover

i was messing around with transform and when i added it to a hover and it didn't work.

I wanna make a share button that when you hover it 3 buttons show them selves

transform works correct but when i use it in pseudo selector:hover its not working.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto auto 100px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

img[src="instagram.svg"] {
  z-index: 1;
}

img[src="linked in.svg"] {
  z-index: 2;
}

img[src="telegram i.svg"] {
  z-index: 3;
}

img[src="share btn.svg"] {
  z-index: 4;
  transition: 600ms;
}

img[src="share btn.svg"]:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 600ms;
}

img[src="telegram i.svg"]:hover {
  transform: translate(30px, 30px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="instagram.svg" alt="your browser sucks">
  <img src="linked in.svg" alt="your browser sucks">
  <img src="telegram i.svg" alt="your browser sucks">
  <img src="share btn.svg" alt="your browser sucks">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stack two `position: absolute` items with the same size over each other you will only be able to trigger `:hover` on the item with the highest `z-index`

You'll also run into problems with user experience by putting your translates on the :hover of an img, instead try wrapping it in a container (as I did with the div class="share" below)

try this CSS

```
      div {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 10px auto auto 100px;
        position: relative;
      }

      img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
      }

      img[src="instagram.svg"] {
        z-index: 1;
      }

      img[src="linked in.svg"] {
        z-index: 2;
      }

      img[src="telegram i.svg"] {
        z-index: 3;
      }

      img[src="share btn.svg"] {
        z-index: 4;
        transition: 600ms;
      }

      .share {
        position: relative;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
      }
      .share:hover {
        height: 120px;
      }
      .share:hover > img[src="share btn.svg"] {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 600ms;
      }
      .share:hover > img[src="telegram i.svg"] {
        transform: translateY(30px);
      }
      .share:hover > img[src="linked in.svg"] {
        transform: translateY(60px);
      }
      .share:hover > img[src="instagram.svg"] {
        transform: translateY(90px);
      }
```

with this HTML

```
    <div>
      <div class="share">
        <img src="instagram.svg" alt="your browser is suck">
        <img src="linked in.svg" alt="your browser is suck">
        <img src="telegram i.svg" alt="your browser is suck">
        <img src="share btn.svg" alt="your browser is suck">
      </div>
    </div>
```